# To find days in which order will be completed

Tags: percentages

A company asks for production of $x$ number of goods. The company produces $y$ number of goods, daily out of which z% are unfit for sale. To find in how many days will the order will be completed ?

How do i solve this? Should i assume that it produces 1 unit per day or something otherwise please give me hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company produces y number of goods per day. Since $z \ \%$ are unfit for sale, the company can only sale $y\cdot (1-z \ \%)$ goods, or $y\cdot(1-\frac{z}{100})$ goods.

Now you have to calculate the ratio of the number of ordered goods ($x$) and the expression above. This ratio has to be rounded up, because in general the ratio is not a whole number. This gives you the number of days the company needs to complete the order.